# Python OpenPyXl dataframe_to_rows to starting at specific cell

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, openpyxl

Is there a way to set the dataframe_to_rows: function of OpenPyXl to start at a specific cell instead of cell A1. Right now I use this. But I don't see any way to get this to start at cell... B7 for example.

```
for r in dataframe_to_rows(df1, index=False, header=True):
        sheet.append(r)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start at the seventh row, just create six empty ones. If you want to start at the seventh column just pad the row from the dataframe with a list of `None` that is wide enough.